# quilljs copyCode module - Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'

Tags: javascript, typescript, dom, copy, quill

I am creating a **copyCode** plugin for QuillJs. Everything seems to be working for the plugin, however, when a space is created between the **text** and the **code-block**, you get this error:

```
Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node'
```

Here is the code:

```js
const copyContentIntoClipboard = (rawData: string) => {
  const encodedContent = encodeURIComponent(rawData);
  const filteredEncodedContent = encodedContent.replace(/%EF%BB%BF/g, "");
  const targetContent = decodeURIComponent(filteredEncodedContent);
  const tmpHolder = document.createElement("textarea");
  tmpHolder.value = targetContent;
  document.body.appendChild(tmpHolder);
  tmpHolder.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(tmpHolder);
};

const CodeBlock = Quill.import("formats/code-block");

class CopyCode extends CodeBlock {
 copyBadge: HTMLDivElement | null;
  domNode: HTMLElement;
  container: HTMLElement | null;
  parent: HTMLElement;
  copyHandler: EventListener;

  _mountContainer() {
    const container = document.createElement("div");
    container.classList.add("ql-container");
    if (this.domNode.nextSibling) {
      this.domNode.parentElement?.insertBefore(
        container,
        this.domNode
      );
      container.appendChild(this.domNode); // <-- error starts here
      this.container = container;
    }
  }
  _dismountContainer() {

    if (this.container) {
      this.container.parentElement?.insertBefore(
        this.domNode,
        this.container.nextSibling
      );
      this.domNode.parentElement?.removeChild(this.container);
    }
    this.container = null;
  }

  _mountBadge() {
    const copyBadge = document.createElement("div");
    copyBadge.contentEditable = "false";
    copyBadge.classList.add("ql-badge", "ql-badge-copy");
    copyBadge.textContent = "copy";
    this.domNode.parentElement?.insertBefore(
      copyBadge,
      this.domNode.nextSibling
    );
    const copyHandler = (e: MouseEvent) => {
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
      const target = e.target as HTMLElement;
      const codeArea = target.previousSibling;
      const copyCode = codeArea?.textContent?.trim() || '';
      if (!codeArea) {
        return;
      }
      copyBadge.textContent = "copied!";
      setTimeout(function() {
        copyBadge.textContent = "copy";
      }, 2000);
      copyContentIntoClipboard(copyCode);
    };
    copyBadge.addEventListener("click", copyHandler, true);
    this.copyHandler = copyHandler;
    this.copyBadge = copyBadge;
  }
  _dismountBadge() {
    const badgeIsInDom = this.domNode.parentElement?.contains(this.copyBadge);
    if (this.copyBadge && badgeIsInDom) {
      this.copyBadge.removeEventListener("click", this.copyHandler, true);
      this.copyBadge.parentElement?.removeChild(this.copyBadge);
    }
    this.copyBadge = null;
    this.copyHandler = () => {};
  }

  _mount() {
    this._mountContainer();
    this._mountBadge();
  }

  insertInto(...args: any) {
    super.insertInto(...args);
    const allowCustomMount = !this.copyBadge && !this.container && this.parent;
    if (allowCustomMount) {
      this._mount();
    }
  }
  remove() {
    this._dismountBadge();
    this._dismountContainer();
    super.remove();
  }
}
```

Here is the **StackBlitz**: https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-ggvuuy?file=index.html

I believe the error is caused by QuillJS believing the code-block should be a **pre** block instead of a **div** block containing a **pre** block.  However, I don't know how to fix it...

Any ideas?

Comment: I don't get any error in your provided code. Could you explain more?

Comment: Create a space between the code-block and text above the code block as I mentioned above (just press enter)... or try and select the code block to turn it back into text etc...

Comment: Still nothing. Everythings fine. What browser do you use? Please update the Stackblitz with the code that gives error and also provide some screenshots

Comment: I just tested it on chrome, edge, and firefox and the error still exists.  Try and put a space between "some text here" and the actual code block (starting with Quill.register) You will get an error.  It is not a browser problem.  You can also select all of one code block, hit the code button, which should turn it back to text, and you get the error: https://typescript-ggvuuy.stackblitz.io/

Comment: @Jonathan the issue with your code was that `Quill` maintains a structure in which if it keeps detail about what is the current domNode what is its next node of current node and previous node of current and childrens, it use that to insert element either into or before, when you moved pre code tag inside container structure changed in `DOM` but `Quill` is not aware of it, when it internally calls insertBefore on parentNode `ql-editor` container and uses pre tag `DOM` node as reference to insertBefore which is now not its child.....

Comment: that's why it throws `Failed to execute 'insertBefore' on 'Node': The node before which the new node is to be inserted is not a child of this node`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of extending `formats/code-block` you can use **Modules** to extend `Quill`

```
import hljs from "highlight.js";
import "highlight.js/styles/monokai-sublime.css";
import "./style.css";
import Quill from "quill";

hljs.configure({
  languages: ["javascript", "python"] 
});

const copyContentIntoClipboard = (rawData: string) => {
  const encodedContent = encodeURIComponent(rawData);
  const filteredEncodedContent = encodedContent.replace(/%EF%BB%BF/g, "");
  const targetContent = decodeURIComponent(filteredEncodedContent);
  const tmpHolder = document.createElement("textarea");
  tmpHolder.value = targetContent;
  document.body.appendChild(tmpHolder);
  tmpHolder.select();
  document.execCommand("copy");
  document.body.removeChild(tmpHolder);
};

class CopyCode {
  quill: any;
  options: any;
  container: HTMLElement;
  unusedBadges: HTMLElement[] = [];
  reference: { [index: string]: {
    parent : HTMLElement | null,
    copyBadge  : HTMLElement | null
  } } = {};

  constructor(quill: any, options: any) {
    this.quill = quill;
    this.options = options;
    this.container = this.quill.addContainer('ql-badge-container');
    this.quill.root.parentNode.style.position = this.quill.root.parentNode.style.position || 'relative';
    this.registerCodeBlock();
    this.quill.on('editor-change', () => {
      Object.values(this.reference).forEach((item) => {
        this.addCopyBadge(item);
        this.repositionCopyBadge(item);
      })
    });
  }

  registerCodeBlock = () => {
    const self = this;
    const CodeBlock = Quill.import("formats/code-block");
    let counter = 0;
    class CopyMode extends CodeBlock {
      domNode: HTMLElement;
      insertInto(...args: any) {
        super.insertInto(...args);

        const index = String(counter);
        const _node = this.domNode;
        _node.setAttribute('data-index', index);
        counter++;
        self.reference[index] = { parent : _node, copyBadge: null };
      }
      remove() {
        const index = this.domNode.getAttribute("data-index");
        if (self.reference[index] && self.reference[index]['copyBadge']) {
          const copyBadge = self.reference[index]['copyBadge'];
          copyBadge.style.display = 'none';
          self.unusedBadges.push(copyBadge);
        }
        delete self.reference[index];
        super.remove();
      }
    }
    Quill.register(CopyMode, true);
  }

  addCopyBadge = (obj: any) => {
    if (obj.copyBadge != null || obj.parent == null) {
      return;
    }

    const index = obj.parent.getAttribute('data-index');
    const copyBadge = this.unusedBadges.length ? this.unusedBadges.shift() : document.createElement("span");
    copyBadge.style.display = 'block';
    copyBadge.contentEditable = "false";
    copyBadge.classList.add("ql-badge", "ql-badge-copy");
    copyBadge.textContent = "copy";

    const copyHandler = (evt: MouseEvent) => {
      evt.stopPropagation();
      evt.preventDefault();
      const codeArea = obj.parent;
      const copyText = codeArea?.textContent?.trim() || '';
      if (!codeArea) {
        return;
      }
      copyBadge.textContent = "copied!";
      setTimeout(function() {
        copyBadge.textContent = "copy";
      }, 2000);
      copyContentIntoClipboard(copyText);
    };
    copyBadge.addEventListener("click", copyHandler, true);
    this.container.appendChild(copyBadge);
    this.reference[index]['copyBadge'] = copyBadge;
  }

  repositionCopyBadge(obj: any) {
    const parent: HTMLElement = this.quill.root.parentNode;
    const specRect = obj.parent.getBoundingClientRect();
    const parentRect = parent.getBoundingClientRect();

    Object.assign(obj.copyBadge.style, {
      right: `${specRect.left - parentRect.left - 1 + parent.scrollLeft + 4}px`,
      top: `${(specRect.top - parentRect.top + parent.scrollTop) + 3}px`,
    });
  }
}

Quill.register("modules/copy-code", CopyCode);

const quill = new Quill("#editor", {
  modules: {
    syntax: true,
    'copy-code': true,
    toolbar: {
      container: ["code-block"]
    }
  },
  theme: "snow"
});
```

Here working [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/typescript-hpk9vc?file=index.ts)

Comment: @Jonathan please check if it is what you need if any problem you can message me here

Comment: A few problems here, although I like that you're thinking outside the box.  The code does not create new copy buttons, or add and remove them if you add/create code-blocks.  The css does not keep it inside the copy button as the example code does etc.  It really should be in the css file, although not technically a requirement.  Fix this, and you get the points.

Comment: @Jonathan there seems to be some issue with `StackBlitz` it is loading script before document loaded completely that why calculation of position is incorrect if you transcompile locally and use it will work.

Comment: While the copy button is now centered, it does not create new "copy-buttons" each time a new code-block is formed.  It also does not remove the "copy-code" button when you edit a code block to be normal text.

Comment: @Jonathan I have update code to work on code block add/remove and position change please check if you find any bugs that need to be fixed.

Comment: This looks great! Only thing, can you remove the "defaultOptions" and put it directly in CSS?  Also, the "right" and "top" are not customizable if you keep it in the code with "repositionCopyBadge".  Is it possible to put that in CSS as well since it is not a changing value?  The goal is to avoid all inline styles at all costs.  This is why there was a container in the old code for each code-block instead of "Object.assign" to hack the position.  The other option I see for these is a <pre><div copy-code></div><code>....</code></pre> like structure...

Comment: @Jonathan `defaultOptions` can be removed and moved to css file

Comment: @Jonathan the problem is `copyBadges` are place outside of `CodeBlock` to its parent grandparent thats why when they are added they will be position outside of `CodBlock` they needed to be positioned correctly to pre `CodeBlock` thats why right and top styles cannot be moved to css file, when there is a change in editor `CodeBlock` position changes but `copyBadges` remain at same position it needs to be updated thats why i have created `repositionCopyBadge` function.

Comment: Could this not be fixed by placing it inside a container like I mentioned above, or a ql-container that my original code used?

Comment: @Jonathan no as i know because that will create issue as explained `Quill` maintain a `DOM` structure which references previous node, next node, children and scroll which are used for to insert element either into or before if i created container and move `CodeBlock` into it, it will create issue because `Quill` references `ql-syntax` pre tag as child of `editor` which will not be true if i move it inside `ql-container`

Comment: @Jonathan if still any doubt/issue/problem we can chat

Comment: Got it. I will go ahead and give the you points.  Could you move the defaultOptions to the css file? I could not get it to work.

Comment: @Jonathan i have already removed `defaultOptions`.